# Laravel Optional Url Slug Correcting

Tags: laravel

I'd like to correct a potentially incorrect slug in a url to a post, just like Stack Overflow does, as seen here:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413983/completely-incorrect-slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413983/laravel-optional-slug)

Let's take the following url as an example:
`www.example.com/posts/5/some-slug-here`

My route is as follows and it works:
`Route::get('/posts/{id}/{slug?}', [...]`

But the following url also works:
`www.example.com/posts/5/some-wrong-slug-here`

I have access to the slug when the url is hit by fetching the post by id.
I'd like to update the url to be correct. Is this possible without using Javascript?

Comment: fetch post by using both id and slug like this  `Post::where('id', $id)->where('slug', $slug)->first();`

Comment: That's not quite what I want. I'd like to avoid querying on the slug and would like urls with incorrect or non-existent slugs (but correct ids) to work. I'd just like urls to be corrected on page load.

Comment: do you want to add slug in url but post should not fetched based on it right ?

Comment: yes, i'd like to fetch the post by id, and add the slug afterwards for readability (exactly as stack overflow does).

Comment: your route is fine, just fetch the post by id and redirect it to new url with your correct slug, if we added any wrong slug in SO it redirect to correct slug

Comment: Thank you very much. I've answered my own question and given you credit. If you copy my answer and post it yourself, I'll mark you as the Best Answer :)

Comment: you have already added answer, how can add my answer now. My answer is same as yours

Comment: I'm happy to delete my answer if you post the example code I wrote. I'd like you to receive rep for helping :)

Comment: no problem, you can accept your answer and after all you have credited me, thats fine

Comment: great, thanks again :)

Comment: you can accept your answer, so that future user can get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you [rkj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690943/rkj).
I have achieved what I desired by making the slug an optional parameter, fetching the post and then checking if the url slug matches the post slug. If it does, I return a view. If it doesn't, I redirect to the same route, passing the id and correct slug as parameters.

Route example:

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}/{slug?}', 'FrontEndController@single_post')->name('single_post');
```

Controller example:

```
public function single_post($id, $slug = null)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if ($slug != $post->slug)
    {
        return redirect()
            ->route('single_post', ['id' => $post->id, 'slug' => $post->slug]);
    }

    return view('single_post');
}
```